# Styling ListViewItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem

I am trying to remove background color for ListViewItem on hover event as well as when element selected.

I was able to remove background color when item is selected by `<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>` but for some reason `<Style.Trigger>` does not work and background color is not changed when mouse is on ListViewItem.

Here is my code

```
<ListView x:Name="EmergencySectionsListView" MinHeight="210" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:EmergencySectionsControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                
</ListView>
```

I read that triggers in standard ControlTemplate may override triggers in ItemContainerStyle so i tried code below but it didnt work.

```
<ListView x:Name="EmergencySectionsListView" MinHeight="210" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:EmergencySectionsControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Please let me know if more info is needed or question is not clear.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to fix this issue.

Comment: I think you need to also make sure you are setting the background to `transparent` on the user control in your `DataTemplate`.  What is the background-color on `<local:EmergencySectionsControl/>`

Comment: See the different approaches in the answers to the duplicate question. In order to have full control, you would completely replace the ListBoxItem's Template. Be aware that you don't need a ListView, the simpler ListBox base class is sufficient.